# Trouble assigning variables from phao mqtt onMessageArrived function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mqtt

I am using Eclipse Paho with Javascript and I am trying to assign `message.payloadstring` to variables, I declare a variable at the beginning of the script and assign it in the `onMessageArrived` function `if(topic === "AVfanControl/DeviceName") deviceName = message.payloadString;` so I can use it elsewhere as I needed. However, the variables keep common back as undefined. I can see on the HTML the device name, but if I try to `console.log(document.getElementById("device_name").innerHTML);` or `console.log(document.getElementById("device_name").innerText);` I just get an blank `console.log` even though I can see the device name in the HTML on the screen.

```
const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(hostname, port, clientID);

client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});

function onConnect() {
    client.subscribe("AVfanControl/DeviceName");
}

const devName = document.getElementById("device_name");
let deviceName;

function onMessageArrived(message) {
    let topic = message.destinationName;
    if(topic === "AVfanControl/DeviceName"){
        deviceName = message.payloadString;
        devName.innerHTML = message.payloadString;
    }
}
console.log(deviceName); // undefined
console.log(document.getElementById("device_name").innerText); // blank log
console.log(document.getElementById("device_name").innerHTML); // blank log

function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
  }
  
  // // function to compile the string to sens as MQTT
  function messageString(input){
      return new Paho.MQTT.Message(input);
}
```

Comment: `onMessageArrived` will be called when a message is received; your calls to `console.log` will run when the script is initiated (before a message is received). To demonstrate this add `console.log("message received")` in `onMessageArrived` and I think you will see that this output will come after your existing log calls.

Comment: @Brits  thank you for your reply, I see what you mean with the logs, the messages are updating once a second, but the variable  deviceName remains undefined and does not seem to update even after lots of messages have been recieved, if i try to use that variable else where it remains undefined, what have i missed?

Comment: Please update your example to show how you are trying to access `deviceName` "after lots of messages have been received" (I'm assuming you are using a button or timer to trigger this?). The way your example is currently written `deviceName` will always be undefined when `console.log` is called.

Answer (score 1):

"SOLVED" @Brits thank you, as you suggested I needed a timer to update the logs after the initial log to give time for the first messages to come through thank you for your input!

```
const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(hostname, port, clientID);

client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});

function onConnect() {
    client.subscribe("AVfanControl/DeviceName");
}

const devName = document.getElementById("device_name");
let deviceName;

function onMessageArrived(message) {
    let topic = message.destinationName;
    if(topic === "AVfanControl/DeviceName"){
        deviceName = message.payloadString;
        devName.innerHTML = message.payloadString;
    }
}

// interval to log devicename
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(deviceName);
    console.log(document.getElementById("device_name").innerHTML);
}, 1000);
    

function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
  }
  
  // // function to compile the string to sends as MQTT
  function messageString(input){
      return new Paho.MQTT.Message(input);
}
```